# Logistic Regression using Logisticregression() class

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

In the documentation of `Logisticregression()`  offered by sklearn library, it states the following note:

> The underlying C implementation uses a random number generator to
> select features when fitting the model. It is thus not uncommon, to
> have slightly different results for the same input data. If that
> happens, try with a smaller tol parameter.

I have two questions regarding this note :

1. What is the meaning of

> The underlying C implementation uses a random number generator to
> select features when fitting the model

2. What is tol parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Note you reference was added back when the only solver available in `LogisticRegression` was `LIBLINEAR`, and that solver uses coordinate descent: coordinates are examined and adjusted individually, iteratively. The order in which that happens apparently is based on a random number generator.

See also
https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/327225/232706
https://stackoverflow.com/q/38640109/10495893

Probably that note doesn't apply to all the newer solvers, and ought to be clarified.

As for `tol`, it is the tolerance criterion for convergence: when the updates to be made are smaller than `tol`, we say that's good enough and stop iterating. What exactly "the updates" being measured are used may also depend on the solver. See e.g.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/255380/232706
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22243
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11536